# When a question is migrated and the most-recent participant doesn't have an account on the target site, no one is listed on the front page

Tags: feature-request, migration, homepage

[Here is the example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411132/264) I noticed recently (migrated to math.SE from mathematica.SE):

> [image]

I was a little puzzled when I first saw this; of course, normally the user who has most recently edited or posted on the thread is listed next to the time, and even if that account is subsequently destroyed, the user listed as most recently participating is Community. However, it appears that when a question is migrated from a different site and whoever edited or posted most recently does not have an account on the new site, nothing is listed at all.

I'd like to suggest that next to the time (on the question list) either the user's name be displayed, but grayed-out, just like is currently done within the migrated post itself, or that Community be displayed.

Comment: +1 for suggesting [Community](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why wouldn't this be a bug report?

Comment: @Troyen because that's the design they have chosen: when there isn't an actual account, do not show it in the front page. We could leave it as bug but I'm pretty sure it'll just be marked [meta-tag:status-bydesign] and not be "fixed".

Answer (score 2):

This is still happening:

> [image: No user on home page]

The question was from [a user with no Meta Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2638098/user2638098), who asked the question on Stack Overflow and had it migrated to Meta.

> [image: User on question view]

If I look at the Active tab under /questions, the user shows up properly:

> [image: User on questions/active page]